# Spark UDAF to compute Percentiles and Median and Witin IQR Standar Deviation from a frequency Table?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Give that, for multiple candidates, multiple kind of tests are conducted, and each test is conducted multiple times.

Eexample:

> Candidate ID 1, took Test-A
>
> 2722 times score was 10.17 and
>
> 8127 times score was 10.23

```
+---------+------+-----+---------+
|candidate|testID|score|Frequency|
+---------+------+-----+---------+
|        1|     A|10.17|     2722|
|        1|     A|10.23|     8127|
```

For each candidate and kind of test (`group by ['candiate',testID']`), the following has be determined.

1. Mean, Median, Mod and Standard Deviation,
2. Percentile 10 th  and 90 th
3. Mean and Standard Deviation of data within Percentile 10th  and 90th.

Sample data :

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
(1, "A", 10.17, 2722),
(1, "A", 10.23, 8127),
(1, "A", 11.02, 3076),
(1, "B", 25.00, 9232),
(1, "B", 25.20, 9001),
(1, "B", 25.04, 8232),
(2, "A", 10.17, 2722),
(2, "A", 10.23, 8127),
(2, "A", 11.02, 3076),
(2, "B", 24.14, 792),
(2, "B", 24.23, 521),
(2, "B", 24.24, 232)
)).toDF("candidate", "testID", "score", "Frequency")
df.show()



+---------+------+-----+---------+
|candidate|testID|score|Frequency|
+---------+------+-----+---------+
|        1|     A|10.17|     2722|
|        1|     A|10.23|     8127|
|        1|     A|11.02|     3076|
|        1|     B| 25.0|     9232|
|        1|     B| 25.2|     9001|
|        1|     B|25.04|     8232|
|        2|     A|10.17|     2722|
|        2|     A|10.23|     8127|
|        2|     A|11.02|     3076|
|        2|     B|24.14|      792|
|        2|     B|24.23|      521|
|        2|     B|24.24|      232|
+---------+------+-----+---------+
```

Expected Output format:

```
Candiate, Test_ID, Mean, Median, Mod, Std, P_10, P_90, Mean_Q_10_90,Std_Q_10_90
```

The usage of

```
val quants = Array(0.10, 0.5, 0.90)
val quantiles = df.stat.approxQuantile("score", quants, 0.01)
```

is not appropriate it must be a Frequency weighted score.
And if the data is repeated as much as the frequency the data will explode, and that's not a optimized way to solve.

One *SQL Solution*

> // PreProcess

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df_ordered")
val df_ordered = spark.sql("""SELECT candidate,testID,score,Frequency from df_ordered order by candidate,testID,score""").toDF()
df_ordered.show()
df_ordered.createOrReplaceTempView("df_ordered")
```

> // Then

```
    spark.sql("""WITH t1 as (
     SELECT candidate,testID,score,Frequency,sum(Frequency) over (partition by candidate,testID order by score) as sum_f from df_ordered),
     t2 as (
     SELECT candidate,testID,sum(Frequency) as total from df_ordered group by 1,2),
     t3 as (
     SELECT t1.*,t2.total,round(t2.total/2,2) as mid, floor(t2.total/2) as floor_mid,
     round(t2.total/4,2)   as q_25_l, floor(t2.total/4) as q_25_u,
 round(t2.total*3/4,2) as q_75_l, floor(t2.total*3/4) as q_75_u,
     LAG(t1.sum_f) over (partition by t1.candidate,t2.testID order by score) as previous_value
     from t1 JOIN t2
     ON t1.candidate=t2.candidate
     AND t1.testID=t2.testID)
     SELECT t3.*, 
     CASE WHEN t3.sum_f >= t3.floor_mid AND t3.previous_value <= t3.floor_mid THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_median,
  CASE WHEN t3.sum_f >= t3.q_25_l AND t3.previous_value <= t3.q_25_u THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_Q25,
  CASE WHEN t3.sum_f >= t3.q_75_l AND t3.previous_value <= t3.q_75_u THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_Q75
 from t3
     """).show(10)
```

This would almost do things, but for **simplicity and reusability** I am looking for **UDAF**

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, DoubleType, LongType
import pandas as pd

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("QuantileUDAFExample").getOrCreate()

# Your DataFrame
data = [
    (1, "A", 10.17, 2722),
    (1, "A", 10.23, 8127),
    # ... (rest of the data)
]

columns = ["candidate", "testID", "score", "Frequency"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

# Define the UDAF function
@pandas_udf(
    StructType([
        StructField("median", DoubleType()),
        StructField("Q25", DoubleType()),
        StructField("Q75", DoubleType())
    ]),
    PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def quantile_udaf(pdf):
    scores = pdf['score'].tolist()
    frequency = pdf['Frequency'].sum()

    mid = frequency // 2
    q25 = frequency // 4
    q75 = frequency * 3 // 4

    median = pd.Series([scores[int(mid)] if scores else 0.0])
    q25_value = pd.Series([scores[int(q25)] if scores else 0.0])
    q75_value = pd.Series([scores[int(q75)] if scores else 0.0])

    return pd.DataFrame({"median": median, "Q25": q25_value, "Q75": q75_value})

# Use the UDAF in a Spark SQL query
result = df.groupBy("candidate", "testID").apply(quantile_udaf)

result.show(truncate=False)
```

This code defines a pandas_udf named quantile_udaf that calculates the median, Q25, and Q75 for each group of "candidate" and "testID". The quantile_udaf function takes a pandas DataFrame for each group, performs the calculations, and returns a new DataFrame with the results.